# Object orientated php

Tags: php, html, function, object, external

I'v just started to learn object orientated php and I'm running into what I suspect is a very trivial issue. I have two .php files, post.php and testPost.php like so:

```
//post.php
<?php
     class fileWrite{
     public function postMessage($logId, $text, $username){
        //If the original login form was not used then this would not be set
        date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

        $fp = fopen($logId, 'a');

        fwrite($fp, $text);
        fclose($fp);
     }
}
?>

//testPost.php
<?php
    include 'post.php';
    $post = new fileWrite;
    $post->postMessage("log.html", "test", "username");
?>
```

When I run testPost.php this is the output: postMessage("log.html", "test", "username"); ?>

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Look for a typo in the file, for example `$post?>postMessage` instead of `$post->postMessage`, that would end the code tag at `?>` and show the rest of the code in the page.

Comment: You may have just simple in your "log.html" file, you may need to check it.

Comment: Not sure why but this code does work fine on my server but not at all on my computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tested your code and it works nicely, check for a typo or that your script has the extension `.php`. If not this will cause the output to show literally your code.